# How to use C# access VB.NET from progress bar

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have A project for C#

I have B project for VB.NET (include vb.net 's mainFrom )
Project B already Reference A ,because B call A's functions(net dll type).

So How can I in Project A functions access call Project B' mainFrom.proguessbar  ?

(Because I try  Project A  reference B  in visual stdio,It cannot ok .show "reference cycle" message.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual studio is right. What you are trying to do is a cyclic reference and .NET does not allow it. In my humble opinion, your case indicates poor design practices. The only solution would be to alter your design.

If you want to have functionality called from both projects (A and B) this should be placed in a separate DLL (project C) and then referenced by both.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of information on your project, but one option is to use events.

If B already reference A then create events in A. Have B implement those events. A just need to raise events. This will enable A to call functions in B.